# Why cannot we work in millivolt range

Tags: microcontroller

Generally we work in terms of either 5V or 3.3V for the micro controllers. Why cannot we work in millivolt range? Just I wanted to know the limitations of working in millivolts.

Comment: Because gate voltage thresholds and diode drops are a thing

Comment: Probably not a major concern, but still a consideration: if you plan running something at the same amount of power but at lower voltages, expect a proportional amperage increase.

Example: A 5V Arduino running at 40mA = 200mW. To have the same power and run at 100mV (0.2 W / 0.1 V) = 2 Amps

Answer (score 3):

Even if you could design logic circuits to work at sub 100mV logic levels, power supplies that feed the logic are usually quite noisy and this noise will also appear superimposed on the logic signals - getting a logic supply that doesn't produce noise that could turn a 0 into a 1 or a 1 into a 0 would be fairly tricky. You'd be looking at about 30mVp-p noise maximum and probably more like 10mVp-p for decent reliability.

It's not just noise but power supply accuracy too - producing a power supply whose voltage drifts up and down (say) +/-0.25 volts under all load and temperature ranges isn't that hard but doing so (and keeping spurious noise) to below (say) 20mV maximum is a big challenge.

But, as has been mentioned by @PlasmaHH, transistors inside logic gates need a certain voltage to turn on and if you can invent a transistor that can turn on and off reliably with a 100mV range of input voltage then you should become very rich. I'm not saying it's a laws of physics thing but it very well might be.

Remember, the beauty about digital solutions is that they avoid digital corruptions by have a distinct "voltage gap" between high and low. Currently some chips use 0.8V as the logic supply voltage so things are moving this way.

Comment: 0.8V :O? I am just curious, what kind of chips?

Comment: @Golaž core voltages on some MCU chips use 0.8V I believe. Plenty use 1.5 volts.

Comment: @Golaž http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scea033/scea033.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the answers before mine, the best has to do with the gate voltage thresholds and diode drops. Semiconductors switch on and off at minimum voltages based on the materials used. Typical for silicon is 0.7V to 1.2V. Some logic gates need more than one transistor to do their job so a higher voltage is needed. Then some additional supply voltage is needed to make up for losses across a circuit and noise and tolerances. There are materials with lower voltage thresholds, but they are more expensive or more difficult to manufacture, so are less common.

Power supply noise comes mostly from fluctuating load of the circuits it is powering. But it needs to be considered. You don't want a surge in power from one part of a circuit to cause an error in another part of the circuit, so additional headroom is needed to make sure the supply voltage is enough that false ones or zeros are not detected.

The comment about an Arduino needing more current at a lower voltage is just not a correct answer to your question. The poster is probably thinking of a light bulb or heater that needs more current at a lower voltage to provide the same wattage of illumination or heat.

Answer (score 1):

[ULV ICs](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scea033/scea033.pdf) operate at 800mV or even slightly below (775mV for some low power Intel CPUs). Lower voltage is often not an advantage for microcontrollers because their interface with the real world represents a higher portion of system cost than in, say, a smartphone CPU.

If you want to operate a relay, turn an LED on, even change an LCD segment, it takes more than 1 volt, so you need voltage translators for almost everything. You can directly operate many power MOSFETs from a 5V MCU, but your design choices have dwindled few at 1.8V.

Some MCUs today use a lower voltage core voltage and have internal voltage translators for the I/O for just this reason. So you might have a 1.8V core voltage and 3.3V I/O.